# jQuery is not working after postback in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This script is working fine in IE but neither in firefox nor Chrome after postback. Can anyone help? If the words Aching, Pain, Leg etc are found in the page it goes to Default.aspx and brings the explanation for those words. Which I use for tooltip purposes.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
  function pageLoad() {
    var options = {
      exact: "exact",
      style_name_suffix: false,
      keys: "Aching, Pain, Leg"
    }
    $(document).SearchHighlight(options);
    $(".hilite").hover(
      function pageLoad() {
        var selWord = $(this).text();
        var wrd = this;
        $.get("Default.aspx", { q: selWord },
        function pageLoad(data) {
          $(wrd).attr("title", data);
        });
      },
      function pageLoad() { }
    )}
  );
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .hilite {
    background-color: pink;
    cursor: help;
  }
</style>
```

Thanks

Poongdoi

Comment: Please add your HTML or ASP.Net code also. It might help us!

Comment: If you are posting to a different page, make sure that the other page includes the jquery script as well! It would help to include the console errors that are showing up as well.

Comment: The actual problem is with Ajax loading(dynamic content), so you need to rebind events. it can be automatically done if you use jquery on() with body context !

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

I tried the below code and works fine in Chrome, FF. I have done few changes in your existing code and modified event handler with jQuery on() and removed some unnecessary lines.

Please try replacing your old script with this! This will work even after partial post back.

```
    $(document).ready(PageBootStrap);

    function PageBootStrap() {
        var options = {
            exact: "exact",
            style_name_suffix: false,
            keys: "Aching, Pain, Leg"
        };
        $(document).SearchHighlight(options);
        $("body").on("hover", ".hilite", function () {
            alert('calling ..');
            var selWord = $(this).text();
            var wrd = this;
            $.get("Default.aspx", { q: selWord }, function (data) {
                $(wrd).attr("title", data);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Then please update your question with proper code with gridview. We cant help with out exactly identifying the problem!

Comment: thanks, in label its working fine but when i bind the grid only the problem using the master page and yes which doing partial Post Back. Pls help me to get over from this problem.

Comment: Try my updated answer. Also use same question and edit instead of answering(updated question) for your question :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is working finely in all the browser after partial postback.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
if(args.get_isPartialLoad())
{
// Code here 
}
}
```